# Error in Kinematics Equation Derivation

Tags: kinematics, integration, calculus

I am wondering why my following steps fail to derive $\frac{1}{2}at^2+{v_0}t+x_0=x$

$Derivation\,of\,Equation\,1:$
$$a=\frac{dv}{dt}$$
$$a\,dt = dv$$
$$\int_{t_0}^{t}a\,dt=\int_{v_0}^{v}dv$$
$$at-at_0=v-v_0$$
$$at-a(0)=v-v_0$$
$$at=v-v_0$$
$$Equation\,1: at+v_0=v$$
$Derivation\,of\,Equation\,2:$
$$v=\frac{dx}{dt}$$
$$v\,dt = dx$$
$$\int_{t_0}^{t}v\,dt=\int_{x_0}^{x}dx$$
$$vt-vt_0=x-x_0$$
$$vt-v(0)=x-x_0$$
$$vt=x-x_0$$
$$Equation\,2:vt+x_0=x$$
$Substituting\,Equation\,1\,into\,Equation\,2:$
$$(at+v_0)t+x_0=x$$
$$at^2+{v_0}t+x_0=x$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your integration in the "Derivation of Equation 2" is wrong.
In this integral v is a function of t and not a constant. You integrate as v were a constant. You need to introduce the actual expression of v(t) under the integral and integrate over t.